# I need to post a text message to the Facebook page programmatically in Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Hi I am new to iOS development
I need to post a text message to the Facebook page programmatically without typing the message in the box,Can any one suggest a solution?
Now i did like this

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"myPageID",@"to",
                               @"myAppName", @"name",
                               @"myAppDesc", @"description",
                               @"myAppLinl", @"link",
                               @"myApp.png", @"picture",
                               nil];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Using this code I can post Image,Link and the description to my Facebook page,I need to post only the text just like posting comment in the wall post

Comment: what you got as error?

Comment: Its not posting the message,

Comment: if you use ios6,ios6 have a social framework  use that framework to post your Message and image and URL to Facebook,twitter

Comment: I can post url and description together,but not possible to post only text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used recent sdk and present share dialog box modally as below.

```
NSDictionary *facebookShareDict = //loading from plist;
NSMutableDictionary *params =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [facebookShareDict objectForKey:@"params_name"], @"name",
 @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
 [facebookShareDict objectForKey:@"params_descrip"], @"description",
 [facebookShareDict objectForKey:@"params_link"], @"link",
 nil];

// Invoke the dialog
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:
 ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
     }
      //do you stuff here.
  }];
```

Comment: thank you….I want to share just a text message,don't want to share any link and images.

Comment: @Rajith It won't show image and link. If you don't want to link, just discard it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `social.framework`  u can post with text,link, image.

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *FacebookSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [FacebookSheet setInitialText:@"Your message"];
    //[FacebookSheet addURL:url];
   //[FacebookSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo@2x.png"]];

    [self presentViewController:FacebookSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, in this you can post using `SLRequest` but you should have login in facebook from 'Settings'

import header files

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
```

.

```
-(void)facebookSharing
{
    NSString *facebookPost = @"Your message";

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]init];
    [alert setDelegate:self];


        self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountTypeFacebook=[self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
         ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

        NSDictionary *options = @{
                                  ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"278578252298078",
                                  ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email",@"publish_stream"],
                                  ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceEveryone
                                };

        [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountTypeFacebook options:options
                                           completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
        {
            if(granted)
            {
                NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeFacebook];

                facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                NSDictionary *parameters =@{@"access_token":facebookAccount.credential.oauthToken,@"message": facebookPost};
                NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

                SLRequest *feedRequest =[SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:feedURL parameters:parameters];

                [feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Request failed, %@",[urlResponse description]);
                }];

                [alert setTitle:@"Successfully posted."];
                [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
                [alert show];
            }
            else
            {

                [alert setTitle:@"Login to your facebook account first."];
                [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
                [alert show];
            }
        }];
   }
```